# How to increment date (month and year) and set the day to default based on specific conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

My Date should always fall on 8th or 22nd that comes off the input date.

**For Example:**

If the input date is **20190415** then the output date should be **20190422** as that's the nearest date and if input date is **20190424** then the output date should be **20190508**.

**Example1:**
input_date = 20190415 
Expected output_date = 20190422

**Example2:**
input_date = 20190424
Expected output_date = 20190508

**Example3:**
input_date = 20190506
Expected output_date = 20190508

**Example4:**
input_date = 20191223
Expected output_date = 20200108

How do we achieve this using Python?

Comment: By using the datetime module. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried `month = datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m')` and incremented month by one but when its year end then the month is getting incremented to 13 and also i am unable to update the datetime with new values @roganjosh

Comment: Why would you increment _both_ the month and the year?

Comment: Sorry, I just incremented month not the year. But when its year end it should increment year and month by one as per the input date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the day is greater than 22, and if so you set it to the 8th of the next month. If it's between 8 and 22 you set it to 22 of the same month and if it's below the 8th you set it to the 8th of the month. There's probably more elegant ways to do it using date math, but this will work for your scenario.

Use the `datetime` module to find out what the "next month" is. One way to do it is to add a `timedelta` of 1 month to the first of the current month, and then change the date on that `datetime` object to the 8th. Here's a quick example of how that might look like:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

input_date = date(2019, 12, 23)

if input_date.day > 22:
    output_date = date(input_date.year, input_date.month) + timedelta(days=31)
    output_date = output_date.replace(day = 8)
```

You can read a lot more about the details of how the `datetime` module works on [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.day). It's kind of a long read, but I actually have that page bookmarked because I always have to go back and reference how to actually use the module :)

Comment: I got what you said in the first paragraph. Second Para got me confusing. Can you show me an example with actual code? I never used timedelta before.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the input as string, next date can be calculated using timedelta, check out the below code:

```
if 8<datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y%m%d").day < 22:
    delta = 22 - datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y%m%d").day
    print((datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y%m%d") + 
           timedelta(days=delta)).strftime("%Y%m%d"))
elif datetime.strptime(str(input_date), "%Y%m%d").day < 8:
    delta = 8 - datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y%m%d").day
    print((datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y%m%d") + 
           timedelta(days=delta)).strftime("%Y%m%d"))
else:
    delta = (datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y%m%d")+ relativedelta(months=+1)).day -8
    print((datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y%m%d") + relativedelta(months=+1) - 
           timedelta(days=delta)).strftime("%Y%m%d") )
```

Comment: I don't think `relativedelta` is part of the built-in `datetime` package... it would be helpful to mention what package needs importing and if it needs to be installed separately with `pip`

Comment: Yes, relativedelta is a part of dateutil package. Import it as `from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta`